# Create array given number of larger elements to right of each member

Tags: c++, performance, array, interview-questions

I want to improve on my original solution to this problem,
my solution is O(n^2) and I think it's possible to solve in less time

> You have two arrays: A and B. A contains ints and B has pairs: (element from A, the number of elements that are larger than that element and to the right of it in A).
> for example:
> A = [4,3,5]
> B = [(5,0), (3,1), (4,1)]
> Given array B, recreate array A

```
void originalArray(vector<pair<int,int>>& pairVector) {
    sort(pairVector.begin(),pairVector.end());
    int arr[pairVector.size()];
    list<int> arrList;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(int i=pairVector.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        it = arrList.begin();
        advance(it, arrList.size()-pairVector[i].second);
        arrList.insert(it,pairVector[i].first);
    }
    it = arrList.begin();
    for(int i=0;i<arrList.size();i++){
        arr[i]=*it;
        it++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pairVector.size(); i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: What makes this `O(n^2)`? I don't see a nested `for` loop.

Comment: @Casey `std::advance` takes linear time with lists.

Comment: @G.Sliepen As far as I can tell it does work. At least your example: https://godbolt.org/z/aaGWMd.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The code you posted is missing some important parts (`#include` and `using`, probably), which means we can't compile it.  This makes it much harder to test different ways of achieving the same result.  If you [edit] your question to make the code complete, that will improve its chances of attracting good answers.

Comment: A `main` function testing the example would be good, too.

Comment: @BlameTheBits Ahum, you're right, I made a copy&paste error that still managed to compile correctly but cause it to give the wrong output.

Comment: `int arr[pairVector.size()];` -- This is not valid C++.  This should be `std::vector<int> arr(pairVector.size());`

Comment: Can we assume A has unique elements? Or if A=[0,1,0,2] then B=[(0,2),(1,1),(0,1),(2,0)] is valid?